# How to repeat a pattern using cairomm?

Tags: c++, background, repeat, cairo, gtkmm

I have a pattern image that I need to repeat in my `Gtk::DrawingArea` using `cairomm`.

I tried using `Cairo::ImageSource` without luck.

Comment: Could you show a sample of the code you tried and that didn't work?  It could help other users see what can be improved.

Comment: Right... the thing is I didn't find a single example on the internet. So I had to dig up cairo's documentation, finally finding this magic `set_extend` method. No other solution found!

Answer (score 2):

It's easy using `Cairo::Pattern` class:

```
bool MyDrawingArea::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> &cr) {
    Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Pattern> image = Cairo::SurfacePattern::create(Cairo::ImageSurface::create_from_png("my_bg_pattern.png"));
    image_->set_extend(Cairo::EXTEND_REPEAT); // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT!
    cr->set_source(image);
    cr->paint();
}
```